# JavaScript: How to convert UTC date / time to Mountain Time?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, utc

I have been trying to write a script that will take the current time in Denver and output it into a URL.

I have been able to get this far: http://jsfiddle.net/Chibears85/h41wu8vz/4/

JS

```
$(function() {
  var today = new Date();
  var ss = today.getUTCSeconds();
  var nn = today.getUTCMinutes() - 3; //3 minute delay
  var hh = today.getUTCHours() - 6; //Offset UTC by 6 hours (Mountain Time)
  var dd = today.getUTCDate();
  var mm = today.getUTCMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getUTCFullYear();
  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }
  if (hh < 10) {
    hh = '0' + hh
  }

  var today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy + '%20' + hh + ':' + nn + ':' + ss ;
  $('img.r').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    if (url.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
      $(this).attr("src", url + today);
    } else {
      $(this).attr("src", url + "?feature_date=" + today);
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="screen.js"></script>
<img class="r" src="https://mywebsite.com&DateTime=" width="400">
```

It inserts the date into the URL however from 6pm-12am Mountain Time the time breaks (01:00:00 10/20/2018 becomes -5:00:00 10/20/2018 instead of 19:00:00 10/19/2018) and the 3 minute delay offset makes it break every hour from :00-:02 (1:01 becomes 1:-02 instead of 00:59).

I was wondering how I can fix the UTC offset so it doesn't subtract into negatives and offsets the date/month/year as appropriate.

Comment: Are you able to use a plugin ? if so, you can use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/), have a look at the documentation first, if you think you can take help from some plugin, try to do the calculation with that, if you face any complexity, may be I can help to solve it with that, 
Doing so would decrease a lot of code complexity and momentjs would be able to take care of the calculations without any errors relating to timezone or whatever

Comment: I can use MomentJS, I was looking into it earlier today trying to solve the issue but I ran into not being able to figure out how to have MomentJS output the date into the URL for my image.

Comment: so, what you need is to get the current time of Denver and set that to an image's src attribute right ?

Comment: Browsers have varying levels of support for `toLocaleString` options, but depending on your requirements you may be able to use `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/Denver'})`

Comment: Correct, I want the current time of Denver and it to be added to the end of the image src

Comment: As you used a loop, there is possibility of multiple images right ?
If so, do you want all of them to have the time (as it is precise enough to count the seconds too) when the page loads ? or it depends on some event (like a click or hover)
Another question, do you need AM / PM or you want the hours to be 24 H formatted ?

Comment: There are multiple images yes, however they will all have the same date/time. It is precise where it needs the seconds when the page loads, AM/PM is not needed, 24 H format is supported.

Comment: check the answer I posted, hope it helps

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the 3 minute delay you are factoring in?

Comment: The images upload to the server every 3 minutes, but are labled as the exact time they were created instead of published (Image created on 12:03 won't be pushed to server until 12:06)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with pure JS, though I thought of using MomentJS at first.
A good solution would be this:

```js
var today = new Date();
var todayThreeMinutesLess = new Date(today - (3  * 60000)); // to reduce 3 minutes from current time, as 60000 ms is 1 minute;
var today = todayThreeMinutesLess.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/Denver', hour12: false}).replace(', ', '%20');
$('img.r').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('src');
    if (url.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
      $(this).attr("src", url + today);
    } else {
      $(this).attr("src", url + "?feature_date=" + today);
      // just to prevew the url format
      $(this).attr("alt", url + "?feature_date=" + today);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="r" src="https://mywebsite.com&DateTime=" width="400">
```

Comment: This is perfect! Almost exactly what I was looking for. Only addition is the 3 minute offset to account for a delay (03:00 would be 02:57 and so on).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: btw, just out of curiosity, may I know why do you need to minus 3 minutes ? :)

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your browser support needs, you may be able to use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) but be aware that  [locales and options may not be supported in Edge and are not supported in Android webview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility).

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/Denver'})
```

To follow your function through to conclusion and convert UTC time to Mountain Time manually (either Mountain Standard Time or Mountain Daylight Time depending on the time of year), you would have to extend your function to handle daylight savings. For example (this is why libraries like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) are so popular, and may be worth looking into for your needs):

```js
const twoDigit = (d) => (d < 10 ? '0' : '') + d;
const formatDate = (date, time) => {
  date = date.map((x) => twoDigit(x)).join('/');
  time = time.map((x) => twoDigit(x)).join(':');
  return `${date} ${time}`;
};

const getOffset = (month, date, day, hour) => {
  // assume MST offset
  let offset = 7;
  
  // adjust to MDT offset as needed
  if ((month > 2 && month < 10) || (month === 2 && date > 14)) {
    offset = 6;
  } else if (month === 2 && date > 7 && date < 15) {
    if ((day && date - day > 7) || (day === 0 && hour - offset >= 2)) {
      offset = 6;
    }
  } else if (month === 10 && date < 8) {
    if ((day && date - day < 0) || (day === 0 && hour - offset < 1)) {
      offset = 6;
    }
  }
  
  return offset;
};

const getMountainTime = () => {
  const dt = new Date(); // current datetime
  let year = dt.getUTCFullYear(); // utc year
  let month = dt.getUTCMonth(); // utc month (jan is 0)
  let date = dt.getUTCDate(); // utc date
  let hour = dt.getUTCHours(); // utc hours (midnight is 0)
  let minute = dt.getUTCMinutes(); // utc minutes
  let second = dt.getUTCSeconds(); // utc seconds
  let day = dt.getUTCDay(); // utc weekday (sunday is 0)
  let offset = getOffset(month, date, day, hour);
  if (hour - offset < 0) {
    hour = 24 + hour - offset;
    day = day ? day - 1 : 6;
    if (date === 1) {
      if (!month) {
        year -= 1;
        month = 11;
      } else {
        month -= 1;
      }
      
      date = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
    } else {
      date -= 1;
    } 
  } else {
    hour -= offset;
  }
  
  month += 1;
  return formatDate([month, date, year], [hour, minute, second]);
};

const denver = getMountainTime();
console.log(denver);
```

Comment: I noticed that you never use the offset to change the hour at the end. It is still set to the UTC values. Did you mean to use twoDigit(hour - offset)?

Comment: @cwbusacker - good observation. After looking over the code, it was just one of several issues with the original hasty answer. See the edited answer for what I think is now a corrected version that appropriately handles various edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use date-fnc library for this.

```
import { formatToTimeZone } from 'date-fns-timezone';

const value = new Date();
const pattern = 'MMM. DD, YYYY [at] H:mma [MT]';

const outputDate =  formatToTimeZone(value, pattern, { timeZone: 'MST' })
```

This is a link to format options https://date-fns.org/v1.9.0/docs/format

And this is for date-fnc time zones https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.27/docs/Time-Zones